# SQL Server: Join all tables from a table listing their names

Tags: sql-server, join, table

I have a table that contains a list of metrics and their IDs in the format:

```
L6Metrics
| ID   | Name            |
--------------------------
| 734  | L6A_Velocity    |
| 736  | L6B_Velocity    |
| 738  | L6A_Target_Rate |
...
```

Each of these metrics has its own corresponding table containing timestamped historical data. If the metric has ID `X`, then its historical data's table name is `History_tX`. These history tables have the format:

```
History_t734
| DateTime                       | Value |
-----------------------------------------
| 2018-05-04 19:17:41.972 -05:00 | 33.9  |
| 2018-05-04 19:17:51.972 -05:00 | 36.3  |
| 2018-05-04 19:18:01.972 -05:00 | 35.1  |
...
```

Assuming that the timestamps across all of the history tables align, how can I use the `L6Metrics` table to join all of the history tables on `DateTime` to get the following:

```
| DateTime                       | History_t734 | History_t736 | ...
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 2018-05-04 19:17:41.972 -05:00 | 33.9         | 34.9         |
| 2018-05-04 19:17:51.972 -05:00 | 36.3         | 37.4         |
| 2018-05-04 19:18:01.972 -05:00 | 35.1         | 36.5         |
...
```

There are 75 rows in `L6Metrics` (representing 75 history tables) so there would be 76 columns in my result. I have the ability to modify `L6Metrics` if needed.

Comment: It will be query-monster. You must join Metrics table, 75 History tables and additionally a CTE table which collects all Datetimes from all History (one more 75) tables.

Comment: *I have the ability to modify @L6Metrics if needed.* It would be better to collect 75 particular History tables into one table.

Comment: Why do you have separate history tables, do the format differ between them?

Comment: @Lennart, all of the history tables are identical in format: DateTime, Value. The database is actually part of an application so the separate table choice was made by the developers of that application.

Comment: Then I suggest to merge them into 1 and add an attribute for type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I strongly agree with [Lennart's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243087/sql-server-join-all-tables-from-a-table-listing-their-names/243091#comment479718_243087):

> Then I suggest to merge them into 1 and add an attribute for type

...I understand that we don't always have a magic wand to fix someone else's (bad) design. So I would opt for a dynamic SQL approach:

```
DECLARE @sqlcol nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT t0.DateTime', @sqljoin nvarchar(max) = N'';

;WITH tnames AS (SELECT t = N'History_t' + CONVERT(varchar(11),ID),
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM dbo.L6Metrics)
SELECT @sqlcol += N',
' + t + N' = ' + t + N'.Value', 
  @sqljoin += CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN N'
  FROM dbo.' + t + N' AS t0' ELSE N'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.' + t
  + N' ON t0.DateTime = ' + t + N'.DateTime' END
FROM tnames;

PRINT @sqlcol;
PRINT @sqljoin; 

-- when the PRINT output looks right, uncomment these:

-- SET @sqlcol += @sqljoin;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlcol;
```

Given the sample data, results of the `PRINT` output are:

```
SELECT t0.DateTime,
History_t734 = History_t734.Value,
History_t736 = History_t736.Value,
History_t738 = History_t738.Value

  FROM dbo.History_t734 AS t0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.History_t736 ON t0.DateTime = History_t736.DateTime
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.History_t738 ON t0.DateTime = History_t738.DateTime
```

This solution of course relies heavily on this assumption:

> Assuming that the timestamps across all of the history tables align,

And so the choice of the "anchor" table, which provides all of the timestamps, is simply arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of Metrics.ID is static:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DateTime FROM History_t1
              UNION
              SELECT DateTime FROM History_t2
              UNION
              ...
              UNION
              SELECT DateTime FROM History_t75
            )
SELECT cte.Datetime, 
       History_t1.value History_t1_value,
       History_t2.value History_t2_value,
       ...
       History_t75.value History_t75_value
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN History_t1 ON cte.Datetime = History_t1.datetime
LEFT JOIN History_t2 ON cte.Datetime = History_t2.datetime
...
LEFT JOIN History_t75 ON cte.Datetime = History_t75.datetime
```

If, as you claim, "Assuming that the timestamps across all of the history tables align" you can avoid of CTE:

```
SELECT History_t1.Datetime, 
       History_t1.value History_t1_value,
       History_t2.value History_t2_value,
       ...
       History_t75.value History_t75_value
FROM History_t1
LEFT JOIN History_t2 ON History_t1.Datetime = History_t2.datetime
...
LEFT JOIN History_t75 ON History_t1.Datetime = History_t75.datetime
```

The Metrics table not needed at all.

If the list of Metrics.ID is dynamic, use dynamic SQL to build the query text similar to above.

Comment: Thank you. I originally was using a query similar to the second one you posted. Could you elaborate on dynamic SQL? The list of metrics is likely to change.

Comment: @Dallan Obtain the list of metrics in a query, concat them to query text using string aggregate functions into a variable, then execute it. In that case I'd recommend to extract datetimes into CTE table (from one History table, not UNION) - it will simplify query text creation.